# ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to make an update, but seem to keep running into this particular error code. When I run the nested SELECT statement found in the outer WHERE clause I am able to pull up the correct entries that need updating, but once I attempt to run the full statement that should commit the changes, I am met with the error.

```
UPDATE expertise
SET expertise_level = (expertise_level + 1)
WHERE expertise_level = (SELECT UNIQUE expertise_level, cs.instructor_id
    FROM class_section cs JOIN course c ON (cs.course_code = c.course_code)
    JOIN expertise e ON (c.course_code = e.course_code)
    WHERE (expertise_level < 10) AND (year = '2016'));
```

Is there something missing from my syntax or perhaps a better way of structuring the query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery has two columns, but is only being compared to one.  One way to do what you want uses a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE expertise
    SET expertise_level = expertise_level + 1
    WHERE expertise_level = (SELECT expertise_level
                             FROM class_section cs JOIN
                                  course c
                                  ON cs.course_code = c.course_code 
                             WHERE c.course_code = e.course_code AND
                                   expertise_level < 10 AND 
                                   year = '2016'
                            );
```

You may want to use `IN` if there can be multiple matches.

Another option uses `=` or `IN` with a tuple:

```
UPDATE expertise
    SET expertise_level = expertise_level + 1
    WHERE (course_code, expertise_level) =
              (SELECT c.course_code, expertise_level
               FROM class_section cs JOIN
                    course c
                    ON cs.course_code = c.course_code 
               WHERE expertise_level < 10 AND 
                     year = '2016'
              );
```

It is unclear whether the instructor should be included in your logic; it does appear to be the cause of the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your statement...

```
...
WHERE expertise_level = (SELECT UNIQUE expertise_level, cs.instructor_id
    FROM class_section 
...
```

How can
"expertise_level" be equal to "expertise_level, instructor_id" ?